# Extract the bech32 stake address from a shelly address in javascript

Tags: cardano-address

I am looking to get the bech32 stake address from a bech32 shelley address. I think I have to decode the shelley address, take the stake address part and encode it again.

I looked here: https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0019/CIP-0019.md#shelley-addresses

But I did not find enough details to do this. Can anyone give me more exact information?

I am using the javascript bech32 library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bech32

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm trying to extract the stake address from shelley address using java. any tips would be appreciated tks

Comment: Please comment in the comment area only

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to achive this in plain bech32, you need to convert it to hex and than back to bech32 to get retrieve the bech32 stake address.

First you decode the bech32 shelley address

For example converting the address `addr1qxdvcswn0exwc2vjfr6u6f6qndfhmk94xjrt5tztpelyk4yg83zn9d4vrrtzs98lcl5u5q6mv7ngmg829xxvy3g5ydls7c76wu`

gives us

`019acc41d37e4cec299248f5cd27409b537dd8b53486ba2c4b0e7e4b54883c4532b6ac18d62814ffc7e9ca035b67a68da0ea298cc24514237f`

Now, the Stake part of the address is the last 56 bytes of it, which gives us `883c4532b6ac18d62814ffc7e9ca035b67a68da0ea298cc24514237f`.

Converting this to a bech32, we will retrieve the associated stake key `stake1uxyrc3fjk6kp343gznlu06w2qddk0f5d5r4znrxzg52zxlclk0hlq`.

Just a reminder that the address can be mangled, so the owner of the stake rights might not be the same person as the owner of the payment funds.

Comment: Thanks this is what I tried. The problem I had was that the bech32 library I am using restricts the length of the encoded data to 90 characters. I found the limit can be changed so I can decode the address now.

Answer (score 4):

Just a side-note to Marek's answer, don't forget to append the prefix to the stake part!

In this case e1:

```
e1883c4532b6ac18d62814ffc7e9ca035b67a68da0ea298cc24514237f
```

See: [Bech32 encoding stake address from Shelley address in JavaScript returning wrong value](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/bech32-encoding-stake-address-from-shelley-address-in-javascript-returning-wrong/)