# Bech32 encoding stake address from Shelley address in JavaScript returning wrong value

Tags: cardano-address, shelley

I am trying to extract the bech32 stake address from a Shelly address using Javascript. I followed the [example steps outlined in the answer another question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/2004/4335) (thanks for the help!) and put together the following code sample. The interim values are correct until the final step (bech32 encoding the stake portion of the hex-encoded address):

```
import { bech32 } from 'bech32';

// input Shelley address
const address = 'addr1qxdvcswn0exwc2vjfr6u6f6qndfhmk94xjrt5tztpelyk4yg83zn9d4vrrtzs98lcl5u5q6mv7ngmg829xxvy3g5ydls7c76wu';

// decode bech32 shelley address and convert to hex 
const addressWords = bech32.decode(address, 1000);
const payload = bech32.fromWords(addressWords.words);
const addressDecoded = `${Buffer.from(payload).toString('hex')}`;
// ✅ should be 019acc41d37e4cec299248f5cd27409b537dd8b53486ba2c4b0e7e4b54883c4532b6ac18d62814ffc7e9ca035b67a68da0ea298cc24514237f

// stake part of the address is the last 56 bytes
const stakeAddressDecoded = addressDecoded.substr(addressDecoded.length - 56);
// ✅ should be 883c4532b6ac18d62814ffc7e9ca035b67a68da0ea298cc24514237f

// convert to bech32 to get stake address
const stakeAddress = bech32.encode(
  'stake',
  bech32.toWords(Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(stakeAddressDecoded, 'hex'))),
  1000
);
// should be  : stake1uxyrc3fjk6kp343gznlu06w2qddk0f5d5r4znrxzg52zxlclk0hlq
// ❌ returns : stake13q7y2v4k4svdv2q5llr7njsrtdn6drdqag5cesj9zs3h7xjwn42
```

Am I missing a step before bech32 encoding the stake portion of the address? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the prefix, i.e. `e1` in this case.

```
const stakeAddressDecoded = 'e1'+addressDecoded.substr(addressDecoded.length - 56);
```

You have to add `e1` (or `e0` in case of testnet) as prefix.

Check page 113-114 for more details on prefix specifications: https://hydra.iohk.io/build/7918420/download/1/ledger-spec.pdf

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Accepted as the answer - thanks!