# Staking address bech32

Tags: address, cardano-address, bech32

I was trying to extract the staking address from an address and I was able to do that by using the bech32 decode, getting the last 56 bytes and encoding back again.

The question is: following [this](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/bech32-encoding-stake-address-from-shelley-address-in-javascript-returning-wrong), I needed to add `e1` (mainnet) or `e0` (testnet) and it worked perfectly. The only thing though is that I don't know the reason. I mean, solving isn't enough, I wanted to understand why it's necessary to add those bytes as prefix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `e` comes from these address prefixes defined in the CDDL https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/f2a783cf00911b7492e81dd6c7fb8a963f9ce8fe/eras/shelley/test-suite/cddl-files/shelley.cddl#L98

`e` equivalent in binary is `1110`. The `0/1` is the part of the network ID defined in this part of the CDDL https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/f2a783cf00911b7492e81dd6c7fb8a963f9ce8fe/eras/shelley/test-suite/cddl-files/shelley.cddl#L79

Combined they're the `header` that prefixes the `payload` defined here https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/f2a783cf00911b7492e81dd6c7fb8a963f9ce8fe/eras/shelley/test-suite/cddl-files/shelley.cddl#L72