# Blockfrost doesn't find address

Tags: cardano-address, blockfrost

I'm trying to query address details of a yet unused address via blockfrost. If I enter the Address in cardanoscan.io, it shows me the stake key of the address, well and fine. But on Blockfrost it responds with an error "The requested component has not been found". Is there any way to extract the stake key from an unused address (assuming that the unused part is what makes blockfrost stumble), either via blockfrost or via some linux tooling?

Let's assume the address "addr1qyxfhv5dncxmeel2gdsjawv2q2mm73gtdh3ekdxshc557q39v2hfvwfdrl00k3r8x9qwk63fj9d96zlhudvmwsy0j0xse7zj29"
Cardanoscan can lookup the stake key for this https://cardanoscan.io/address/010c9bb28d9e0dbce7ea43612eb98a02b7bf450b6de39b34d0be294f022562ae96392d1fdefb44673140eb6a29915a5d0bf7e359b7408f93cd

I tried to extract via https://hub.docker.com/r/inputoutput/cardano-addresses via

`echo "addr1qyxfhv5dncxmeel2gdsjawv2q2mm73gtdh3ekdxshc557q39v2hfvwfdrl00k3r8x9qwk63fj9d96zlhudvmwsy0j0xse7zj29" | docker run --rm -i cardano-address address inspect`

but I don't receive the stake key in the format I expect it ("stake1....") but like

```
{
    "stake_reference": "by value",
    "stake_key_hash_bech32": "stake_vkh1y432a93e950aa76yvuc5p6m29xg45hgt7l34nd6q37fu6t4h543",
    "stake_key_hash": "2562ae96392d1fdefb44673140eb6a29915a5d0bf7e359b7408f93cd",
    "spending_key_hash_bech32": "addr_vkh1pjdm9rv7pk7w06jrvyhtnzszk7l52zmduwdnf597998sy0j4pt2",
    "address_style": "Shelley",
    "spending_key_hash": "0c9bb28d9e0dbce7ea43612eb98a02b7bf450b6de39b34d0be294f02",
    "network_tag": 1,
    "address_type": 0
}
```

I'm looking for a format like "stake1uyjk9t5k8yk3lhhmg3nnzs8tdg5ezkjap0m7xkdhgz8e8ngj8tttk"

any pointers here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

db-sync based API services such as blockfrost and koios can't find unused addresses because they are not "db-synched"

Cardanoscan uses his own backend and library, to decode the bech32 and extract the stake key, even if it is not used yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer of the blockfrost  support team:

> Our API returns 404 Not Found for any resource that does not exist on
> chain a the moment, even when in theory, it could exist. These are
> typically addresses that haven't been used yet. We can't know that
> someone has generated a new address unless we see it on blockchain.
> Once someone makes a transaction, it will appear on blockchain and
> hence in our API. And it'll stay there forever, even with 0 balance.
> The thing is, there's an infinite number of addresses which can be
> generated. And unless they make a transaction of some sort, they are
> basically "non-existent".

If you want to extract the staking address you can follow these instructions:
[Extract the bech32 stake address from a shelly address in javascript](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/extract-the-bech32-stake-address-from-a-shelly-address-in-javascript)